# how to find the slope of a curve at origin

Tags: derivatives

What is the slope of the curve $x^3 + y^3 = 3axy$ at origin and how to find it because after following the process of implicit differentiation and plugging in $x=0$ and $y=0$ in the derivative we get $\frac{0}{0}$.....how to solve these kinds of problems

Comment: Se http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Advanced%20Level/Sketch%20graph.htm

Comment: see here https://books.google.at/books?id=50u2SnGlw2UC&pg=SA3-PA13&lpg=SA3-PA13&dq=slope+of+x%5E3%2By%5E3%3D3axy+at+the+origin&source=bl&ots=iXPUNHkYKC&sig=fvTegycQTjZcxMqnimXMkSt_1rI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwion-qUk_LJAhVFzxQKHV_jDNYQ6AEIWDAH#v=onepage&q=slope%20of%20x%5E3%2By%5E3%3D3axy%20at%20the%20origin&f=false

Answer (score 2):

As $(x,y)$ get close to $0$, the behavior of the solution set is determined by the terms of *smallest* total degree.

For small $x$ and $y$, the values of $x^3$ and $y^3$ will be *much smaller* than $3axy$, so the zeroes of the function will be approximately where the zeroes of $0=3axy$ are -- that is, near the origin the curve will look like the solutions to that, which is just the two coordinate axes. So the curve will *cross* itself at the origin, passing through the origin once horizontally and once vertically.

(This is also why implicit differentiation can't work at the origin -- the solution set simply doesn't look like a straight line there under any magnification).

Comment: Plz explain the line "This is also why implicit differentiation can't work at the origin -- the solution set simply doesn't look like a straight line there under any magnification"

Answer (score 1):

$3x^2 dx + 3y^2 dy = 3ay \, dx + 3ax \, dy$

$(x^2 - ay)dx = (ax - y^2)dy$

If you let $x=0$, you get $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac ay$

and, as $y$ approaches $0$, the slope becomes undefined; i.e., the tangent line becomes a vertical line.

If you let $y=0$, you get $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = x$

and, as $x$ approaches $0$, the slope becomes $0$; i.e., the tangent line becomes a horizontal line.
[image]

Comment: Actually, this is a bogus argument. If you let x=y, you end up with y' = -1. Huh?